# Permissions in Liferay to manage site

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Scenario: User-X creates an organization's private site and assigns User-Y to that organization. I want to make User-X unable to change any settings of the site assigned to User-Y (i,e. only User-Y should be able to change site's setting)

Basically, I have to disable the admin (i,e. User-X) to change the setting of a site assigned to another user.

So, is there any way, in Liferay, to do so ?

Comment: "_I want to make User-X unable to change any settings of the site assigned to User-Y_ " Please elaborate what do you mean by _change any settings_

Comment: I mean site settings .. for example look and feel of the pages of that site

Comment: For `Pages`, in Admin panel, under `Permisssions` , you can configure which all type of Users (Admin, Owner, your own defined user role) can view/modify/delete etc